# Batch file to Repeat line detected and copy after last repitition of text file

Tags: batch-file

Need to copy only selected portion of the text file. A sample txt file is given below.

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
ccc
fff
ggg
```

Kindly notice that 'ccc' is repeated twice here(in 3rd and 6th line). I need to copy the lines of this text file after the last repetition of 'ccc'(i.e.. on 6th line here) OR to be more clear i want to copy 7th and 8th line in this sample text file to a new text file. I have tried it to the extent given below. The below given program doesn't manage to populate my new text file i.e.. check_txt_edited.txt Kindly help me to fulfill my task.

```
@echo off
cd E:\Projects\Retrieve-data
set file=check.txt
type nul > check_txt_edited.txt
IF EXIST %file% (
    for /f %%a in ('type "%file%"^|find "" /v /c') do set /a ttl_cnt=%%a
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n /c:ccc %file%') do set /a line=%%i
    set /a startline=%line%+1

    for /f %%b in (%file%) do (
        set /a startline+=1
        if %startline% leq %ttl_cnt% echo %* >> check_txt_edited.txt
            )   
) ELSE (
    ECHO %file% does not exist
    pause
)
```

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Thank you,
Regards,
Prasad Poduval

Comment: what about a small script? what about [python](http://www.python.org/)?

Comment: Do you know what the repeated value is or is necessary to first determine it?

Comment: Sorry guys. I failed to edit my program based on the sample text file provided to you.Yes i do know the repeated value. It is 'ccc' in the sample text. Sorry for the confusion there.Now the program is updated

Comment: I do need a batch file itself alex. Python may not work.

Answer (score 0):

First step: search for last occurence of "ccc" (%x%=linenumber):

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n /x /c:"ccc" %file%') do set x=%%i
```

Second step: write all lines below that line:

```
more +%x% %file%>check_txt_edited.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "target=ccc"
SET occur=2
SET "repro="
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q24865244.txt) DO (
 IF defined repro ECHO(%%a
 IF "%%a"=="%target%" (
  SET /a occur-=1
  IF !occur!==0 SET "repro=Y"
  )
)
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q24865244.txt` containing your data for my testing.
Produces newfile.txt

Simply set the target and occur count to suit.

I've assumed that you want the target to match the line.

If you want to include the target line, moe the `if defined` after the closing parenthesis of the `if "%%a"` command.